# A triangle has sides $2n, n^2+1$ and $n^2-1$ prove that it is right angled

Tags: triangles

I've tried using Pythagoras theorem but it always results in a silly answer like $n=n^2$ or something.

I'm nearly 100% sure this is done with Pythagoras but I'm not sure which way to do it

Comment: $(n^2-1)^2=n^4-2n^2+1$ and $(n^2+1)^2=n^4+2n^2+1$ and $(2n)^2=4n^2$

Comment: Sounds like you make a mistake in your algebra. You should have ended with something like $n^2 = n^2$. If you show your work, you will probably find your error yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$ 4n^2 = (n^4 + 2n^2 +1) - (n^4 - 2n^2 + 1)$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a particular case of [Pythagorean triples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple). All such triples $(a,b,c)$ with $a^2+b^2=c^2$ can be generated by two integers $m,n$ as:
$$
a=n^2-m^2,\qquad b=2mn,\qquad c=m^2+n^2
$$
(the identy $a^2+b^2=c^2$ is easely verified). In your case we have $m=1$.